# import org.springframework cannot be resolve even after adding dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I get errors that say `The import org.springframework cannot be resolved` for all the imports. My POM.XML is as follows: i am sure that i have included all the necessary dependencies. No clue, why this is happening. Help

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.app.controller</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstController</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>webapp spring</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>FirstController</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

FirstController.java

```
package my.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hi")
public class FirstController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello LA");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of IDE are you using? how do you sync your IDE project with Maven?

Comment: Eclipse. and i use mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: do you see the spring dependencies in your Eclipse project build path? have you tried mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse ?

Comment: Forget about `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.  Use m2e plugin (which is already built-in in eclipse in recent versions).  By the way, does your project build when using mvn in command line manually?

Comment: I had the same problem, read few post and tried a command `mvn clean compile` make sure you are in correct directory, and then go to eclipse and refresh project. (This fixed my problem).

Answer (score 4):

- Check the output of `mvn clean install`. And see if the concerned jar is being downloaded. Look into `$HOME/.m2/repo/....` to see if it is indeed present.
- In the IDE be sure you have configured the Build Path correctly (e.g. in eclipse, Right-click project, Build-Path, 3rd tab)
- Besides, I guess it should be `pom.xml`(lowercase) and not `POM.XML`, as I believe case matters. But I guess you put that in the post unkownigly.

Answer (score 2):

it's a very common issue with people who new to Eclipse with Maven.
To fix just follow steps below:

1. Select the **project in Eclipse**
2. Right clich to open **context menu**.
3. Select **Maven/Update Project** ( or Alt + F5)

Elipse then will reload/update new dependencies for you.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

you are using annotations from later versions of Spring
Update your Spring version in the pom.xml to reflect a more current correct Spring version

From

```
 <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

To

```
 <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change spring version from

```
<spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

to

```
<spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had met this problem just a moment ago, I just ran a spring mvc demo.My IDE is IntellJ, I just reimported all maven projects, everything is OK now. I just clicked the right top corner reimport all maven project button, everything is OK, you can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by right click on the pom.xml in Eclipse and 'Maven Add Dependency'
`org.springframework
spring-web
3.0.4.RELEASE`

Answer (score 1):

I ItelliJ: Maven Projects -> Reimport

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the M2_REPO variable was not configured properly.

Solved by go to project Properties => Java Build Path => Add Variable => Configure Variables => New and added M2_REPO to be ~/.m2/repository.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by deleting all the Problems (select all the Problems, delete it) and doing a Project Clean. This works for the the most stubborn of issues. For some reason Eclipse does not delete all the Problems before doing a clean.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```